# Controlling a web application via a command line utility

Tags: javascript, web-services, batch-file

I have a web application which I normally access using https://url:port/login.jsp

Upon the login, the web application displays the jobs, that had been performed earlier, in a tabular format. Right above the table, it has two options - *1) create a new job 2) open the job (this gets enabled when a job has been selected from the table)*

I am trying to create a command line utility that will open this web application and open the jobs listed in the table, one by one, and click on the *test button* available on the following page. The result of the test connection has to be printed by the command line utility.

Right now, I came up with a batch file that opens up the URL, logs in using the following commands:

```
@if (@CodeSection == @Batch) @then

set SendKeys=CScript //nologo //E:JScript "%~F0"

start https://url:port/login.jsp

timeout /t 5

%SendKeys% "username{TAB}"
%SendKeys% "password{ENTER}"

goto :EOF

@end

// JScript section

var WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell");
WshShell.SendKeys(WScript.Arguments(0));
```

After the login, I want it to open available jobs one by one and test the connection. I am not sure how I can make the batch file take control of these processes.

Also, currently, the execution of script lets the user see the whole process. It would be good to have it run in the background and just get the result of the test in the command prompt.

How to take control of the job table and open jobs one by one? Is there a better way than SendKeys method to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You could be happy with soapUI / jmeteter in a batch mode